# How do I get Sublime Text 3's open file dialog to highlight a matching file while typing like it did before the 3.2 (Build 3200) update?

Tags: sublimetext3, openfiledialog, debian-stretch

For several *decades*, the **standard practice** of file explorers across several operating systems, such as open file dialogs, has been to highlight a matching file when the user types while the file list has focus.

I just updated Sublime Text to version 3.2 (Build 3200, Debian 9) which has replaced this decades-long ingrained behavior with a *search filter*.  If, for example, I need to open file "product-something-or-other" and I type "product", instead of the first file starting with "product" being highlighted like *expected* in this kind of interface, the file list is filtered to list all files containing "product" in their names, including *several* which come alphabetically before "product", and without highlighting the first file with a name starting with "product".

This forces me to either finish typing out "product-something-or-other", or arrow-down several times, or move my hand from the keyboard to the mouse and double-click on the file I want.  These methods all require several more physical actions than normal and are therefore *counterproductive*.  How do I turn off this assinine feature and get back the "highlight while typing" behavior?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this either, but this is the behaviour of GTK3 file dialogs now; or if you will, Sublime (which is now GTK3 and not GTK2) just uses whatever file dialog the library presents.

Comment: This is clearly a design decision made by somebody with an art degree and not somebody who actually uses a computer for productivity.